# API method /posts/{ids}/revisions returns "<strong></strong> " for hot questions and hot meta posts

Tags: bug, hot-questions, revisions-list, api

The API seems to return `<strong></strong>`  instead of `<b>Became Hot Network Question</b>`  as the `comment` field for the revision item in which a post became a HNQ. [Here](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/posts/59189/revisions?site=politics.stackexchange&filter=!5RC-)9_aw3mg*i)3*vUhU3Wfl&order=desc&sort=creation&key=lL1S1jr2m*DRwOvXMPp26g(() is an example:

```json
{
  "items": [
    {
      "creation_date": 1603605600,
      "comment": "<b>Tweeted</b> <a href=\"https://twitter.com/StackPolitics/status/1320243696386887680\" rel=\"nofollow noreferrer\">twitter.com/StackPolitics/status/1320243696386887680</a>"
    },
    {
      "creation_date": 1603389320,
      "comment": "added 160 characters in body"
    },
    {
      "creation_date": 1603285228,
      "comment": "add link to video"
    },
    {
      "creation_date": 1603250312,
      "comment": "<strong></strong> "
    },
    {
      "creation_date": 1603250312,
      "comment": "<strong></strong> "
    },
    {
      "creation_date": 1603224427,
      "comment": "edited title"
    },
    {
      "creation_date": 1603222400,
      "comment": "edited tags"
    },
    {
      "creation_date": 1603221507
    }
  ],
  "quota_remaining": 9225,
  "total": 8
}
```

As you can see, there are two revisions with `comment` `"<strong></strong> "`, which is incorrect.

---

This also happens with Hot Meta Posts ([example](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/posts/404236/revisions?site=meta.stackoverflow&filter=!*JxbFHbLOtgCBkdy&key=lL1S1jr2m*DRwOvXMPp26g(()):

```json
{
  "items": [
    {
      "post_id": 404236,
      "comment": "edited title",
      "revision_guid": "B72342B3-F325-4F96-B429-A6B927787932"
    },
    {
      "post_id": 404236,
      "comment": "<strong></strong> ",
      "revision_guid": "C5DABD00-2B1B-4109-80B6-6B986B9EB01A"
    },
    {
      "post_id": 404236,
      "comment": "added 17 characters in body",
      "revision_guid": "AF996D6F-EF21-41CC-A044-5BE783317681"
    },
    {
      "post_id": 404236,
      "revision_guid": "5E7A3F8A-65ED-4B7E-8254-A74213F32B8E"
    }
  ],
  "has_more": false,
  "quota_max": 10000,
  "quota_remaining": 9889
}
```

Comment: Strong is stronger than bold, they upgraded the API.